# Forming a sub query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Using a subquery, at what branch(es) can the book “A Guide to SQL” be found? List the branch name, branch location, and the number of copies available. Do not explicitly test for book code 669X. Let MySQL do the work for you. Insert your query and results here:

Is the bottom code below correct? I'm confused with how to enter this in a subquery and this seems simpler

use Henry_Books;

```
select branch_name,branch_location,inventory.on_hand
from branch,inventory,book
where branch.branch_num = inventory.branch_num
and title = "A guide to SQl" ;
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for subquery:

```
select branch_name,branch_location,
  COUNT(inventory.book_id) NumberOfCopies
from branch
inner join inventory on branch.branch_num = inventory.branch_num 
inner join book on inventory.book_id = book.book_id
where book.title = "A guide to SQl" 
GROUP BY branch_name, branch_location;
```

(I don't know what is the relation between the two tables `book` and `inventory` so I am guessing it will be bases on `book_id`)

---

If need to do it using a subquery, then you can do this, which is more complex and no need for it at all:

```
select branch_name,branch_location,
  ( SELECT COUNT(inventory.book_id) 
    FROM inventory on
    inner join book on inventory.book_id = book.book_id 
    WHERE branch.branch_num = inventory.branch_num 
     AND book.title = 'A guide to SQl'
  ) AS NumberOfCopies
from branch
```

Note that, this is a correlated subquery.

Comment: I was trying to answer it through a sub query instead of regular way

Comment: @Link45 - No need for a subquery instead of subquery, you have join which  will give you what you want. I will update my answer with a subquery,

Comment: Okay thank you. I want to compare this to what the sub query would look like

Comment: @Link45 - Subquery in this case will be too complex and no need for it at all. Just use `join` as in the answer.\

Comment: Yes I understand that but if you could show me the sub query because that’s the way I’m supposed to write it for class I’m just not understanding how

Comment: That’s the simplest sub query?

Comment: @Link45 - Yes this is the simplest sub query I can think of :D

Comment: List the customer number, customer name, and sales rep that have the same rep number as customer number 282. This will need to be a subquery and do not test for sales rep 35 explicitly. 
  use premier_products;

  select customer.customer_num,customer.customer_name,rep.first_name
  (SELECT rep_num
   from rep,customer
   where rep.rep_num = customer.rep_num
   and customer_num = 282)
    from customer,rep;

im confused with how to form a subquery with the following question.

Comment: @Jeannetee Rachale

Answer (score 0):

Simple use Join between tables , and grouping

[image]

in your case :

```
    SELECT branch_name,branch_location,inventory.on_hand 
    FROM branch AS branch
    LEFT JOIN inventory AS inventory ON (branch.branch_num = inventory.branch_num )
    LEFT JOIN book AS book ON (branch.branch_num = book.branch_num )
WHERE  branch.branch_name = "A guide to SQl"
    ORDER BY branch.branch_name
    GROUP BY branch.branch_name
```

---

if you like to go with Sub Query which is not recommended

[image]

```
SELECT branch_name,branch_location,on_hand AS (SELECT on_hand FROM inventory WHERE branch.branch_num = inventory.branch_num  )
    FROM branch AS branch
    LEFT JOIN book AS book ON (branch.branch_num = book.branch_num )
WHERE  branch.branch_name = "A guide to SQl"
    ORDER BY branch.branch_name
    GROUP BY branch.branch_name
```

Comment: List the customer number, customer name, and sales rep that have the same rep number as customer number 282

Comment: @Link45 that would be different question you need to ask and different thread , since your question has been answered you need to mark the best answer for your question